# display data to listbox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox

Listbox does not show data. Verified data is in database and I am not getting an 
error.  Not sure where/what is wrong.  Thanks in advance.  My code is attached.

```
 private void UpDateList()
        {
            //  add data connection and fill data set.

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dataSource);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string sqlString = "select * from Suppliers";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            foreach(DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
                foreach(object value in dRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    values.Add(value);
                    _Suppliers.Add(values);
                }
            }    
            lstSuppliers.DataSource = _Suppliers;
            lstSuppliers.Update();
        }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should get in the habit of wrapping your connection objects (and any other objects implementing iDisposable) is a USING statement to ensure they always get disposed of. For the question at hand couldn't you simply set the datasource to your table instead of moving all the data into an array? No need to loop here.

Comment: Have you tried running a Sql Server profile trace?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda pointless to enumerate one bindable data collection and transfer data into another bindable collection so it can be bound. Just have your list use the default view of the datatable that already holds the data (allows sorting, filtering etc)

E.g.

```
LstSuppliers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
LstSuppliers.DisplayMember = "column name goes here of what to show eg SupplierName";
LstSuppliers.ValueMember = "column whose value to use for lstSuppliers.SelectedValue e.g. supplierId";
```

And then for example, not required but an example possibility:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "[SupplierName] ASC";
```